# Flutter Image picker is already active, null exception

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

In my flutter project I am getting exception whenever I am trying to pickup an image either from Camera or Gallery using the `image_picker` plugin of flutter.

For the very first time it asks for the permission and when I allow the camera it throws

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser
>   android.content.pm.ProviderInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

After that, it throws an exception for every subsequent tries

> PlatformException(already_active, Image picker is already active,
>   null)

If I try to choose the camera or gallery even after restarting the app.

```
var imageSource;
if (source == CAMERA_SOURCE) {
    imageSource = ImageSource.camera;
} else {
    imageSource = ImageSource.gallery;
}

try {
     final file = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: imageSource);
     if (file == null) {
     throw Exception('File is not available');
 }
```

Below are the dependencies:

```
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
firebase_auth: ^0.8.1
cloud_firestore: ^0.9.0+1
firebase_core: ^0.3.0+1
firebase_messaging: ^3.0.1
firebase_storage: ^2.0.1
intl_translation: ^0.17.3
http: ^0.12.0+1
xml: ^3.3.1
uuid: ^2.0.0
shared_preferences: ^0.5.1+1
flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.2.7
google_sign_in: ^4.0.1
flutter_signin_button: ^0.2.5
image_picker: ^0.5.0+2
mlkit: ^0.9.0
path_provider: ^0.5.0+1
```

Thanks for your time! I also tried to upgrade my flutter to the latest version.

Comment: Hey, Sam. Please edit your question and add some of your code so we can see what's going on. The functions that call the image picker, the button press etc.

Comment: I have added some more details

Comment: It's been awhile but if you are stil interested on this topic, it seems to be a bug: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28550

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After upgrading flutter and dependencies and flutter clean made it working...

Answer (score 5):

Finally I was able to resolve it.

I updated all my dependencies and flutter SDK and then I did Flutter clean and it started working..

Thanks all for your time and help

Comment: did you test it by uninstall the app and install it again?

Comment: Yes, It is working working after removing the app from the device and reinstalling..

Answer (score 3):

Change in android/build.gradle classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'

This worked for me.

Comment: it's working with the classpath you said,
thank's Bro

Answer (score 3):

If you have channel based code i.e bridge between Native Android and Flutter..
In MainActivity
on Activity Result
..
try adding ..

> super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

Comment: Can you please elaborate or share a code snippet of usage. I am trying to pick image in flutter add-to-app approach.

Answer (score 3):

Anyway, I have the same issue when using Image Picker.

I have solved the trouble, it needs to provide permission to access the camera and storage memory on the release mode.

On Android:
Add lines on file `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`: inside the manifest tag

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

On IOS:
Add lines on file `Info.plist`:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow access to photo library</string>

<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow access to camera to capture photos</string>
```

Good luck, hope it will be useful!

Answer (score 2):

I updated package from `0.5.4+3` to `^0.6.5+2` and that solved my problem.

If you read the changelog, you will see every issue fixes: https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker#-changelog-tab-

Answer (score 0):

Removing and Reinstalling application as stated in the comments is fix the problem.

Comment: i tried it, but is not helping. it is not a good use case for customer, to be forced to reinstall the app. :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I haven't given access to "Files". While connecting USB, give access as shown :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please add this line in your `MainActivity.kt` class:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the same error in my case, I added super onActivity result, maybe you are overriding any method on MainActivity with using super,

Ref answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65525354/15721679

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); // add this line.
```