# PlatformException(already_active, Image picker is already active, null) on huawei y5

Tags: flutter

```
E/flutter (15907): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(already_active, Image picker is already active, null)
E/flutter (15907): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:564:7)
E/flutter (15907): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:316:33)
E/flutter (15907): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (15907): #2      ImagePicker.pickImage (package:image_picker/image_picker.dart:59:40)
```

How can I resolve this image picker dependency error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uninstall the app then install again, if issue still persist maybe you are overriding any method on MainActivity with using super, like for me adding super onActivity result helped, which I found from this link.

Ref link https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19103#issuecomment-412647536

```
  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); // had to add this line.
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I haven't given access to "Files". While connecting USB, give access as shown :

[image]