# Facing trouble with image picker in release apk(Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, android-11, imagepicker

The image picker works fine in the debug apk but crashes in the release apk.
The picker opens the gallery to select the image but when I tap on it, throws the following exception
`PlatformException(already_active, Image picker is already active, null, null)`. The plugin works fine on sdk version uptill 28/29, but I'm using 30.
Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong or if I have to do something in the manifest file or such thing. I'm using the basic `Image picker` plugin. Please help me out, Thank you.

Comment: Is there any Code you could add to your question to make it more specific?

Comment: By code do you mean the code snippet that I've used to upload an image or the error/exception that gets throwed?

Answer (score 0):

You can find similar issue here that may help you to resolve this:
[Flutter Image picker is already active, null exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54737551/9558020)