# Flutter : Image Picker Exception

Tags: flutter, dart, imagepicker

I'm trying to pick image by image picker package , it was working but now I get this error

> Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(already_active, Image picker is
> already active, null, null)

and this is the code which I'm using :

```
 File _image;
 final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future getImage() async {
    var image = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      _image = File(image.path);
      Navigator.pop(this.context);
    });
  }

  Future getCameraImage() async {
    var image = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      _image = File(image.path);
      Navigator.pop(this.context);
    });
  }
```

Explain :
when clicking to pick image ( gallery or camera ) first time it was opening the gallery and after selecting image , the setState for _image = File(image.path); not work and after that I'm trying to click to pick image again then this exception is appear

Comment: When exactly does this error occur? Or what sequence of events trigger it?

Comment: when clicking to pick image ( gallery or camera ) first time it was opening the gallery and after selecting image , the setState for _image = File(image.path); not work and after that I'm trying to click to pick image again then this exception is appear

Comment: @MariamYounes Why are you using `Navigator.pop(this.context);` after storing the image to the variable?

Comment: @SouvikBiswas to close the dialog which allow user to choose between gallery or camera

Comment: @MariamYounes Try calling `Navigator.pop(this.context)` outside the `setState`, you should never call it inside a `setState` call.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
File _image;
 

  Future getImage() async {
    ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
    var image = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      _image = File(image.path);
      Navigator.pop(this.context);
    });
  }

  Future getCameraImage() async {
    ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();
    var image = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      _image = File(image.path);
      Navigator.pop(this.context);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Same exception 
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(already_active, Image picker is already active, null, null)
 StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:582:7)
 MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:159:18)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `Navigator.pop(this.context)` outside the `setState`, you should never call it inside a `setState` call:

```dart
 File _image;
 final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future getImage() async {
    var image = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      _image = File(image.path);
    });
    Navigator.pop(this.context);
  }

  Future getCameraImage() async {
    var image = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      _image = File(image.path);
    });
    Navigator.pop(this.context);
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your solution , but sorry it doesn't work :(

Comment: @MariamYounes check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54737551/flutter-image-picker-is-already-active-null-exception. This might help you, also I think you are using an older version of `image_picker` try updating it to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing hybrid with android
Find the `onActivityResult` of `ImagePickerDelegate` and put a breakpoint on it. You will find that you will not get here after selecting the photo.
So you need to find this line of code

```
activity.startActivityForResult(pickImageIntent,REQUEST_CODE_CHOOSE_MULTI_IMAGE_FROM_GALLERY)
```

You need to determine who this activity is, and then add:

```
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
```

to it.
If you are a flutter fragment

You also need to call:

```
fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
```

Like this:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
  fragment?.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally I found the answer

in main activity

super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);